# Joomla pass json data in variable from component to module

Tags: joomla, module, components

I have a component and in one view, I would like to include a module that I have created.

The view is accessing the module in this way:

```
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_graphit');
$module->params = "action=".json_encode($this->params);
$modhtml = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
echo $modhtml;
```

And in the module, in the xml file, I have defined a field:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="action" type="textarea" default="" label="JSON data" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

And in the module, I get the data like this:

```
$action = $params->get('action');
```

So, this is working if I use in the component view a small text but if I try to pass JSON data, nothing is working anymore. I have tried also to change in the xml file the type to text but no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.